# Which virtualization technology for old linux box

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, debian-squeeze

I have old PIV 1.8ghz, 512MB memory, 40GB HDD, computer with Debian squeeze on it. I currently work on it by connecting to it over SSH.  I'm interested in testing/learning/trying out/playing  with some things on Linux  so I would like to set up a virtual machine on this box for this purpose so in case I mess up something pretty bad I won't need to reinstall whole OS ( PC currently doesn't have any monitor either).

Since PC is 32 bit I'm not able to use KVM to which I'm used to. Can I get some recommendation for a technology that would suit my purpose?

P.S. 
I know that memory is somewhat low, but I intend to use only 1 VM so I hope it will be enough.

Comment: You could use a simple chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably run [XEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen#Host:_Unix-like_systems) on that machine and run para-virtualized  guest OSes. In fact, Debian includes XEN 4.01 in its stable release.

Context: I run XEN on my Asus 1012B. I didn't know it was a 64 bit box, so I put in the 32 bit version of CentOS 5 and later on configured it as a XEN host. Turns out to be useful in testing 32-bit packages, but long term, not a terribly optimal configuration as XEN host. ;)

Comment: Even if the Processor is 64-bit, you may be better off running 32-bit on low-RAM boxes, because a 64-bit OS usually allocates larger blocks for equivalent data structures (int, double, float, string, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Since that machine is so old, the only option that I can really recommend is virtualbox.  I would install a Linux or BSD distro without a gui, install a gui-less virtualbox, and manipulate it entirely through the terminal.

Honestly, your machine is underpowered for anything useful, though.  You would be better off using any other non-netbook computer with multiple cores, unless you're already maxing out the memory, even if it's your primary machine.

The VirtualBox command line management tools reference page is here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Comment: Underpowered for anything useful? Not impressed.

Comment: I suppose that it depends on what "useful" means to the individual.  Personally, I think he'll spend more time trying to trim his bare-metal install down to the bare minimum (a useful exercise in it's own right) than his stated goal of playing with virtualization.

Comment: The power of a commodore64 was sufficient to landing on the the moon.

Comment: The OP didn't state that that was his goal, and I have yet to see a Commodore64 host a virtualized instance of a modern OS, so I fail to see the relevance.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try some **light-weight** virtualisation technologies like [OpenVZ](http://wiki.openvz.org/Main_Page), [VServer](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org), or [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/).

They might be a better fit for a resource constrained machine than more main-stream PV or HVM options such as Xen/KVM.

Debian has them available as well.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox, VMWare (Server was free haven't checked recently), KVM's Grandfather QEmu. I have run Virtualbox on some really old and busted hosts, like P3 and anywhere as little as 256-512 MB RAM.

Comment: VMware Server is still free, however it has reached end of support in June 2010.

Comment: @xeon Nooooooo! /endvader